# Docker build command does not work for Nodejs

Tags: node.js, docker, express, dns

I am new into docker.
I am using linux to run docker. Docker successfully installed. But
When I run docker command `sudo  docker build .` I always getting the error. How can i solve the issue?

[image: Error screnshot]

My docker file is

```
FROM node:14

WORKDIR /app

COPY package.json .

RUN npm install


COPY . .

EXPOSE 3000

CMD [ "node", 'app.mjs' ]
```

Nodejs package.json file

```
{
  "name": "1_getting-_started_docker",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "app.mjs",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.17.1"
  }
}
```

app.mjs

```
import express from 'express'

import { connectToDatabase } from './helpers.mjs';

const app = express();

app.get('/', (request, response) => {
    response.send('<h1>Hi there</h1>');
});

await connectToDatabase();

// https://robinwinslow.uk/fix-docker-networking-dns
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Dockerfile looks fine, so it is very likely related to the Docker installation. You should probably try to restart the docker daemon: https://docs.docker.com/config/daemon/systemd/ and/or restarting your computer.

If that doesn't work pls show your complete logs that appear on the error message.

Comment: M. Perez  This is my daemon.json file. Is this correct? I am still getting the same error. ```{
    "dns": ["118.179.223.10", "8.8.8.8"],
    "data-root": "/mnt/docker-data",
    "storage-driver": "overlay2"
}```

Comment: Which logs file you want nodejs or Docker?

Comment: see your picture, the line before the last one indicate a path the see the log: /root/.npm/_logs.......

Comment: Yes what @Jerome said, look at the path of the error message: /root/.npm ...